# Avoiding duplicate joins in Rails ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scenario where I have SQL joins somewhere in the query chain, and then at some further point I need to append a condition which needs the same join, but I don't know at this point whether that join exists already in the scope. For example:

```
@foo = Foo.joins("INNER JOIN foos_bars ON foos_bars.foo_id = foos.id")
....
@foo.joins(:bars).where(bars: { id: 1 })
```

This will product an SQL error about duplicate table/alias names.

The reason I write the SQL join manually in the first instance is to improve the efficiency as the classic rails AREL join will product two INNER JOINS where in my case I only need the one.

Is there a recommended way around this? Some way to inspect the joins currently in a scope for example.

**Response to comment:**

With a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship Rails produces two `INNER JOINS` like this:

```
SELECT "journals".* FROM "journals"
INNER JOIN "categories_journals"
  ON "categories_journals"."journal_id" = "journals"."id"
INNER JOIN "categories"
  ON "categories"."id" = "categories_journals"."category_id"
WHERE "categories"."id" = 1
```

Whereas I believe I can do this instead:

```
SELECT "journals".* FROM "journals"
INNER JOIN "categories_journals"
  ON "categories_journals"."journal_id" = "journals"."id"
WHERE "categories_journals"."category_id" = 1
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What kind of profiling did you do to prove that your more 'efficient' way of doing the joins was actually better? Actually, what makes you think you only need the one join?  AREL won't build out unnecessary joins even if you repeatedly try to join the same table over and over.

Comment: I updated my question because it was too long for a comment @messick.

Comment: I suggest just letting AREL do it's thing.  You solution is defeating one of the main benefits of ORM, which is 'automagically' having objects that map to database tables.  If joining up to the Categories table is really that much of a performance hit, I'd go back and think about if Rails is really something you want to be using.

Comment: I think it's a bit stupid to say just because I choose to write certain aspects in SQL for performance reasons that I'm defeating the object of an ORM or using Rails itself. Many things you can't do at all in AREL and have to use SQL. I have a query with about 6 many-to-many model joins, if I can cut the number of SQL joins in half why wouldn't I? To use Rails isn't to give in to performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to universally use string joins. Unbeknownst to me Rails actually `uniq`s string joins -- so as long as they're **string identical** this problem doesn't occur.

*[This article](http://pivotallabs.com/pivots-patch-rails-named-scope-with-the-joins-can-cause-table-aliasing-issues/)* put me on the scent, the author exhibits the exact same problem as me and patches Rails, and it looks like the patch was implemented a long time ago. I don't think it's perfect though. There should be a way for rails to handle hash parameter joins and string joins and not bomb out when they overlap. Might see if I can patch that ..

EDIT:

I did a couple of benchmarks to see if I was really worrying about nothing or not (between the two ways of joining):

```
1.9.3p194 :008 > time = Benchmark.realtime { 1000.times { a = Incident.joins("INNER JOIN categories_incidents ON categories_incidents.incident_id = incidents.id").where("categories_incidents.category_id = 1") } }
 => 0.042458 
1.9.3p194 :009 > time = Benchmark.realtime { 1000.times { a = Incident.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: 1 }) } }
 => 0.152703
```

I'm not a regular benchmarker so my benchmarks may not be perfect but it looks to me as though my more efficient way does make real world performance improvements over large queries or lots of queries.

The downside of joining in the way I have done is that if a `Category` didn't exist but was still recorded in the join table then that might cause a few problems that would otherwise be avoidable with the more thorough join.